# OpenShift - can't install RHC

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-client-tools

I'm trying to install RedHat Client tools to use with OpenShift. I've following installation instructions from here: https://developers.openshift.com/en/getting-started-windows.html#client-tools

I've downloaded all the latest tools:

Ruby

```
ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
```

Git

```
git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1
```

When I try to run `rhc setup` I get the following errors in the command line (tried running as an administrator)

```
C:\Users\Administrator>rhc setup
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
: cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/au
thentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb
:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/ssh_helpe
rs.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:77:in `<class:Wizard>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:7:in `<module:RHC>'
            from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/wizard.rb
:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/
base.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/
account.rb:2:in `<module:Commands>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands/
account.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54
:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:189:in `block in load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:188:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/commands.
rb:188:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/lib/rhc/cli.rb:36
:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rhc-1.35.3/bin/rhc:20:in `<t
op (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/rhc:23:in `<main>'
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use an older version of ruby, like 1.9.3 or 2.0 instead of 2.2.  You also should file a bug report at https://bugzilla.redhat.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online